# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath selects multiple cells glitch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if ([selectedCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {

    [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

} else {

    [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
}

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```

}

Okay so this is weird.

What's going on:  When there are over about 10 or so rows, everything gets all glitchy and if I select the first row, the 8th and 10th row are selected. If I deselect the 8th and 10th row, nothing happens. If I select the 8th and 10th row, they get selected but the 3rd and 5th row get selected.

This happens on AppCoda's tutorial project too: http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-handle-row-selection-in-uitableview/

Is this just XCode? If it is, this is a huge glitch.

Comment: You shouldn't set the accessory type here.  You should set a value in your data model indicating which row is selected, and use your data model to show (or hide) a checkbox in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  Then reload the row (or `reloadData`) after you've updated your data model.

Comment: if it is okay for you to take an array extra in your code i can help on this issue in another way

Answer (score 2):

In your implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you need to check whether the row is selected, and set the accessory view accordingly.  Otherwise, the accessory view is simply whatever it was when the cell went into the reuse queue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're forgetting to update the cell after you change the accessory type:

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```